# X-Men Chronological Order

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, chronology, suggested-order

What order should the X-Men franchise (including Deadpool 1 & 2, Logan and the Wolverine) be watched in? Different sites give me different answers (due to the time travel in Days of Future Past).

Comment: You asked what should be watched or what's chronology? It's hardly the same, not to mention details like time travel...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chronological order goes like this:

- *X-Men: First Class* [established by *Days of Future Past* to be a prequel to the original timeline]
- *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* [explains how Wolverine got into the situation he's in in *X-Men*]
- *X-Men*
- *X2: X-Men United*
- *X-Men: The Last Stand*
- *The Wolverine*
- *X-Men: Days of Future Past* [here, the timeline is reset]
- *X-Men: Apocalypse*
- *Dark Phoenix*
- *Deadpool*
- *Deadpool 2* [be aware that some of the marketing spoils the ending of *Logan*]
- *Logan*

Note that some of the films (particularly *X-Men Origins* and *The Wolverine*) feature flashbacks to events that happened prior to the events of *First Class*, while others directly contradict one another.